# jQuery radio button check action doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following jquery code:

```
$("input[name=weight_goal_type]:radio").click(function () {
    alert('it worked');
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$("input[name=weight_goal_type]:radio").change(function () {
    alert('it worked');
});
```

I have also tried to do:

```
$("#id_weight_goal_type_1").change(function () {
        alert('it worked');
    });
```

My radio group looks like this:

```
<li>
    <div class="goal_left_box">
        <div class="dc_box_input">
        <input checked="checked" class="rd-input" id="id_weight_goal_type_0" name="weight_goal_type" type="radio" value="0" />
            <input type="radio" class="rd_input" name="name-a1">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        Maintain Weight
     </div>  

    <div class="cl"></div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="goal_left_box">
        <div class="dc_box_input">
        <input class="rd-input" id="id_weight_goal_type_1" name="weight_goal_type" type="radio" value="1" />
            <input type="radio" class="rd_input" name="name-a1">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        Lose Weight
     </div>  

    <div class="right_select prst_box wight_box">
        <label>Pounds Per Week</label>
        <div class="prst_box_input">
        <input class="wight" id="id_weight_change_increment" name="weight_change_increment" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.00" />  lbs
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cl"></div>
</li>
```

Here is a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/4naznyu3/

I don't know why this does not fire.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @APerson no there isn't any console errors

Comment: You HTML is broken. You are missing a closing `</div>` for `.goal_left_box` and for `</div>Maintain Weight</div>` you use a closing `<div>` to start the block. This is probably causing Jquery to not be a be able to find the element you want correctly.

Comment: can you please post as answer so this could be marked as answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my html was broken as Noah Huppert pointed out.